How to get the credit card number from stripe using react js
I have the following code
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {
    CardNumberElement,
    CardCvcElement,
    CardExpiryElement,
    useStripe,
    useElements
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import axios from "../../axios";
import Spinner from "../Spinner/Spinner";
import "./Checkout.css";
import Alert from "react-bootstrap/Alert";
import {AddToCalendarButton} from "add-to-calendar-button-react";

    export const Checkout = ({event}) => {
        const stripe = useStripe();
        const elements = useElements();
        const [error, setError] = useState(null);
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
        const [couponSuccess, setCouponSuccess] = useState(false);
        const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);
        const [couponCode, setCouponCode] = useState(null);
        const [cost, setCost] = useState(0);
    
        const handleSubmit = async (ev) => {
            ev.preventDefault();
    
            const {firstName, lastName, email} = ev.target.elements;
    
            if (firstName && firstName.value.length && lastName && lastName.value.length && email && email.value.length) {
                if (!stripe || !elements) {
                    return;
                }
    
                try {
                    const { token, error } = await stripe.createToken({ type: "card" })
    
                    if (!token) {
                        setError("Please provide your credit card details.");
                        return;
                    }
                    if (error) {
                        setError(error);
                        return;
                    }
                    const eventId = event.id;
                    const firstNameValue = firstName.value;
                    const lastNameValue = lastName.value;
                    const emailValue = email.value;
                    const tokenValue = token.id;
                    const timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
    
                    axios.post("/api/orders", {
                        token: tokenValue,
                        eventId,
                        couponCode,
                        firstName: firstNameValue,
                        lastName: lastNameValue,
                        email: emailValue,
                        timezone
                    }).then((response) => {
                        if (response.data.error) {
                            setError(response.data.error);
                        } else {
                            setSuccess(true);
                        }
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        console.dir(error);
                        setCouponSuccess(false);
                        // setError(error);
                    });
                } catch (error) {
                    console.dir(error);
                    setCouponSuccess(false);
                    // setError(error);
                }
            } else {
                setCouponSuccess(false);
                setError("Please complete all required fields.");
            }
        };
    
        return (
            <div className="container Checkout">
                <div className="row">
                            <h2 className="Checkout_CardDetailsH2">Card details</h2>
                            <div className="row StripeElementWrapper">
                                <label htmlFor="cardNumber">Card Number</label>
                                <div className="stripe-card StripeElement--empty">
                                    <CardNumberElement/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="row StripeElementWrapper">
                                <label htmlFor="expiratonDate">Expiration Date</label>
                                <div className="stripe-card StripeElement--empty">
                                    <CardExpiryElement/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="row StripeElementWrapper">
                                <label htmlFor="securityCode">Security Coe</label>
                                <div className="stripe-card StripeElement--empty">
                                    <CardCvcElement/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button disabled={!stripe} className="btn btn-primary">Enroll</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };
    
    export default Checkout;

stripe is not picking up the credit card element, cvc, and expiration date to create a card token. Can someone please help?

First, Tokens are legacy and you really should use PaymentMethods, so I recommend stripe.createPaymentMethod instead: https://docs.stripe.com/js/payment_methods/create_payment_method
Second, you need to actually pass your instance of your CardNumberElement to stripe.createToken() (or stripe.createPaymentMethod()). This would look like:
const { token, error } = await stripe.createToken(elements.getElement(CardNumberElement));

This will automatically submit the data associated with each rendered Element on your page when creating the Token.
